# Pick First mobile number automatically HintRequest android

Tags: java, android, android-pendingintent

I want to pick first phone number automatically from HintRequest android.

Is there any possible solution for it?

is there any solution, user cannot dismiss the HintRequest Dialog without selecting at least one mobile number?

[image: check this screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

```
// Example From Kotlin

        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.3.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:17.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'

        // Class : AutoDetectMobileNo

            class AutoDetectMobileNo internal constructor(context: Context) {
                private var googleApiClient: GoogleApiClient? = null
                private val context: Context
                private val appCompatActivity: AppCompatActivity = context as AppCompatActivity
                fun requestPhoneNoHint() {
                    googleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                        .enableAutoManage(
                            appCompatActivity
                        ) { }
                        .addApi(Auth.CREDENTIALS_API)
                        .build()
                    val hintRequest = HintRequest.Builder()
                        .setHintPickerConfig(
                            CredentialPickerConfig.Builder()
                                .setShowCancelButton(true)
                                .build()
                        )
                        .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
                        .build()
                    val intent =
                        Auth.CredentialsApi.getHintPickerIntent(googleApiClient, hintRequest)
                    try {
                        appCompatActivity.startIntentSenderForResult(
                            intent.intentSender,
                            RC_HINT,
                            null,
                            0,
                            0,
                            0
                        )
                    } catch (e: Throwable) {
                        Log.e("PHONE_HINT", "Could not start hint picker Intent", e)
                    }
                }

                fun getPhoneNo(data: Intent): String {
                    val cred: Credential =
                        data.getParcelableExtra(Credential.EXTRA_KEY)!!
                    return cred.id
                }

                interface Callback

                companion object {
                    const val RC_HINT = 1000
                }

                init {
                    this.context = appCompatActivity.applicationContext
                }
            }


        // On Your Activity / Fragment

        val autoDetectMobileNo = AutoDetectMobileNo(this)
        autoDetectMobileNo!!.requestPhoneNoHint()

        override fun onActivityResult(
                requestCode: Int,
                resultCode: Int,
                data: Intent?
            ) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
                if (requestCode == AutoDetectMobileNo.RC_HINT) {
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        val mPhoneNumber = autoDetectMobileNo!!.getPhoneNo(data)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: onActivityResult Will only be called when the user is selected any one phone number.Then,  How it will work? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: autoDetectMobileNo!!.requestPhoneNoHint() - this line request your available phone number and list... then based on your selection you will get the phone number onActivityResult val mPhoneNumber.. I'm using Kotlin here

Comment: No. My question is, My application should pick first mobile number alone. User no need to see the list or select any number from list. IS this possible?

Comment: Sure just try it & let me know please

Comment: it shows list of mobile number. that's all. it doesn't do any other special stuff.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207650/discussion-between-mani-kandan-and-noorul).

Comment: @ManikandanKaruppiyah I copied as it is there no change of auto pick of first number. or  you mean to say this works when __HintRequest__ have only one number